# Additional safe area on NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, safearealayoutguide, geometryreader

I am building a SwiftUI app where I have an overlay that is conditionally shown across my entire application like this:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                Group {
                    if myCondition {
                        EmptyView()
                    } else {
                        OverlayView()   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this to adjust the safe area insets of the `NavigationView` and propagate it to any content view, so content is not stuck under the overlay. At least that's how `additionalSafeAreaInsets` in UIKit would behave. Unfortunately, it seems that SwiftUI ignores any `safeAreaInsets()` on a `NavigationView` (the overlay will show up, but safe area is not adjusted).

While I can use a `GeometryReader` to read the overlay size and then set `safeAreaInsets()` on `ContentView`, this will only work for `ContentView` - as soon as I navigate to the next view the safe area is gone.

Is there any nice way to get NavigationView to accept additional safe area insets, either by using `safeAreaInsets()` or by some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems `NavigationView` does not adjust its safe area inset when using `.safeAreaInset`. If this is intended or a bug is not clear to me. Anyway, I solved this for now like this (I wanted to use pure SwiftUI, using UIKit's `additionalSafeAreaInsets` might be an option to):

**Main App File:**

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(SafeAreaController.shared)
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                OverlayView()   
                    .frameReader(safeAreaController.updateAdditionalSafeArea)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SafeAreaController: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = SafeAreaController()
    
    @Published private(set) var additionalSafeArea: CGRect = .zero
    
    func updateAdditionalSafeArea(_ newValue: CGRect) {
        if newValue != additionalSafeArea {
            additionalSafeArea = newValue
        }
    }
    
}

struct FrameReader: ViewModifier {
    
    let changeChandler: ((CGRect) -> Void)
    
    init(_ changeChandler: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) {
        self.changeChandler = changeChandler
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let newFrame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                        changeChandler(newFrame)
                    }
                    
                    return Color.clear
                }
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func frameReader(_ changeHandler: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        return modifier(FrameReader(changeHandler))
    }
}
```

**EVERY Content View that is pushed on your NavigationView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var safeAreaController: SafeAreaController

    var body: some View {
        YourContent()
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                Color.clear.frame(height: safeAreaController.additionalSafeArea.height)
            }
}
```

Why does it work?

1. In the main app file, a `GeometryReader` is used to read the size of the overlay created inside `safeAreaInset()`. The size is written to the shared `SafeAreaController`
2. The shared `SafeAreaController` is handed as an `EnvironmentObject` to every content view of our navigation
3. An invisible object is created as the `.safeAreaInset` of every content view with the height read from the `SafeAreaController` - this will basically create an invisible bottom safe area that is the same size as our overlay, thus making room for the overlay

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ListView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Test")
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("My Overlay")
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(0..<30) { item in
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Next view")
            } label: {
                Text("Item \(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then it IS a problem with the `NavigationView`, isn't it? Because `.safeAreaInset()` doesn't work properly on `NavigationView` (for no apparent reason, or am I missing something?). And yes putting it on `ContentView` works, but is not the desired behaviour (since I want all pushed views to have the same additional safe area inset).

Comment: I think there is a misconception: `NavigationView`itself is not really a view, it's more like a wrapper that tells the inner views how to behave. So the `NavigationView`itself can't deal with a safe area.

Comment: There definitely is something strange going on with `NavigationView`, that's true. I'm not so sure if this is expected behaviour, though. Do you have any source that this is not intended to work? I mean the whole thing is called `Navigation->View<-`, it derives from `View`, it already does change the safe area of its content (for the navigation bar) and if we look at it with a framework like SwiftUI-Introspect it appears to be a wrapper for UINavigationController, which does support this behaviour. To be honest, this seems more like bug than anything else to me, but of course I might be wrong.

Comment: well it turns out you're not wrong – I was  ... look at the code. I just moved it one step further down from the App struct.

Comment: ChrisR thanks for the code, but isn't it what I posted in my original post? Is this working for you (adjusting the safe area of the List)?

Comment: arrrghh ... no it doesn't ...

Comment: so, after making a complete fool out of myself – why don't you put an identical safeAreaInset (e.g. as a ViewModifier) into every single of your views?

Comment: haha I appreciate any attempt to help :D The `.safeAreaInset` can only exist once since I want to create an overlay that stays onscreen when a new screen is pushed (so it should not be affected by the NavigationView push animation). But I solved this now by adding an EnvironmentObject that holds the bottomSafeAreaInset and then I add it to every content view. Kind of cumbersome, but seems to be the best solution without using UIKit.